# Android Custom Map Source

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I need to create a Map View in an Android project where I get custom map tile PNG's from a server. Does anybody know a hassle-less-licensed API to implement such a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the OsmDroid open source map library (see [OsmDroid website](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)) - it loads map tiles from a variety of sources so should be configurable to point to a custom tile server.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Can you give a sample app on how to use OsmDroid